# PHP XML Start Array at Attribute then Array Slice

Tags: php, arrays, xml

Presently have an array created from an XML file then I array_slice to show the last 200 of the array ... which I am pretty sure I have wrong in this code any ways (note I don't start at 0 bcz it's an empty node):

```
$xml_get = 'filename.xml'
$xml_array = json_decode(json_encode($xml_get), 1);
$master = $xml_array['unit'];
// Show Last 200
$master = array_slice($master, 1, 200);
foreach(array_reverse($master) as $arc)
{
$last_id = $arc['@attributes']['id'];
$last_data = $arc['data'];
$last_link = $arc['link'];
// Do stuff with values...
}
```

What I would like to do is to be able to start the array @ an attribute (of the node) and show the 100 before it. My intent is to use the url attribute: address.com/blah/index.php#9439580 as the value for the start @attribute ...

... but after much searching, not sure where to begin with the array. Not sure if I need to chunk it or how to start an array at a particular attribute.

Update with XML sample:

```
<archive>
  <unit id="929495820">
    <data>Blah</data>
    <link>url</link>
  </unit>
  <unit id="929495821">
    <data>Blah</data>
    <link>url</link>
  </unit>
</archive>
```

Comment: Can you include a sample of your XML which shows how you want it to work.

Comment: @NigelRen I included the XML but the XML is not the change. What I want is to print the array from a certain point in the array (the XML data) by starting at a specific node (via attribute) ... so say there are 100's of nodes in the XML, I pull the array but I want it to start at unit id="929495821" and show the next 100 only.

Answer (score 0):

Do not convert XML to JSON for that. You loose the possibility to use Xpath.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<list>
  <item id="1"><data>One</data></item>
  <item id="2"><data>Two</data></item>
  <item id="3"><data>Three</data></item>
  <item id="4"><data>Four</data></item>
  <item id="5"><data>Five</data></item>
  <item id="6"><data>Six</data></item>
</list>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$expression = '//item[@id=4]|//item[@id=4]/preceding-sibling::item[position() < 3]';

foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $item) {
  var_dump(
    [
      'id' => $item->getAttribute('id'), 
      'data' => $xpath->evaluate('string(data)', $item)
    ]
  );
}
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["data"]=>
  string(3) "Two"
}
array(2) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["data"]=>
  string(5) "Three"
}
array(2) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["data"]=>
  string(4) "Four"
}
```

#### The Xpath Expression

- Any `item` element node
  `//item`
- Any `item` element node with the `id` attribute equal to `4`...
  `//item[@id = 4]`
- ... its preceding `item` nodes with the same parent ... 
  `//item[@id = 4]/preceding-sibling::item`
- ... limited to 2 ... 
  `//item[@id = 4]/preceding-sibling::item[position() < 3]`

Xpath expressions act as filters and can be combined with `|`. The example uses the first expression to filter fo the marker node itself and the second for its preceding siblings.

Comment: I have array_reserve() in my foreach bcz I need to display the array from newest to oldest ... how would I apply that to your code? Also, would I turn each array element to value in the same way I have above ie $last_data = $arc['data'];

Comment: `DOMXpath::evaluate()` returns a `DOMNodeList`, you can convert this into an array using `iterator_to_array()`. Or you use a `for`-loop to iterate the node list backwards. Use DOM functions and Xpath to fetch individual values `$xpath->evaluate('string(data)', $item)` is an example for that.

Comment: I am getting zero results in numerous iterations ... can you edit the code to show where iterator_to_array() would go bcz I am not certain if it is screwing up the foreach. interator_to_array($xpath)?